# Javascript and regex: remove evryting except the first character if is a digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some strings like these:

```
var str1 = "1 aaa bbb.";
var str2 = "ccc ddd.";
        ...
```

I would like to use regex and delete everything, except the first digit, if there is a digit.

So, these 2 strings will become:

```
str1 = "1"
str2 = ""
```

can this be done by using

```
str.replace(regex,'');
```

If you can help me with the regex expression please.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I am a beginner in regex. I have tryed to write the regex but without success.

Comment: @Ana: Again: What does your own attempt look like? It's okay if it's wrong, if it were right, you wouldn't be asking the question. :-)

Comment: I have tryed this: str.replace(\d.*,""); but this will delete the digit to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of replacing everything else you could try to match the digit instead.

```
str = str.match(/^\d/);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are a beginner at regex / dont want to use regex for any other reason, theres always the alternative:

```
var str1 = "1 aaa bbb.";
var str1 = parseInt(str1.charAt(0));

if (str1)
    alert(str1);
```